# Gnu plot plotting box plot with error bar

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot box plot with error bar for each of the data in the following file this code doesn’t work:

```
file = 'question8.txt'
header = system('head -1 ' . file)
array = ''
split(header, array)
start_year = 2000
end_year = 2015

set xtics ('' 1)
set for [i=start_year:end_year] xtics add (word(array, i - start_year + 1) i)

set style data boxplot
unset key

plot for [i=start_year:end_year] file using i:i with yerrorbars
```

This is the data:

```
Year:  Avg Temperature:  Max Temperature:  Min Temperature:
1850              7.90              8.95             -2.44
1851              8.18              8.47             -2.76
1852              8.10              8.97             -2.82
1853              8.04              8.79             -3.55
1854              8.21              8.22             -3.12
1855              8.11              7.30             -3.73
1856              8.00              6.64             -5.41
1857              7.76              9.04             -2.69
1858              8.10              8.07             -2.70
1859              8.25              9.77             -2.06
1860              7.96              7.74             -3.26
1861              7.85              7.36             -4.11
1862              7.56              8.46             -1.77
1863              8.11              7.07             -3.85
1864              7.98              8.84             -3.21
1865              8.18              8.19             -2.92
1866              8.29              8.14             -3.31
1867              8.44              7.61             -3.48
1868              8.25              8.21             -3.17
1869              8.43              8.53             -3.31
1870              8.20              7.96             -2.94
1871              8.12              8.23             -3.23
1872              8.19              8.28             -3.44
1873              8.35              7.38             -3.76
1874              8.43              6.68             -4.72
1875              7.86              7.33             -3.33
1876              8.08              8.08             -3.16
1877              8.54              8.28             -3.08
1878              8.83              8.56             -3.31
1879              8.17              7.88             -3.37
1880              8.12              7.34             -3.69
1881              8.27              8.39             -3.02
1882              8.13              7.06             -4.52
1883              7.98              7.57             -4.12
1884              7.77              6.42             -4.62
1885              7.92              7.02             -3.76
1886              7.95              6.86             -4.68
1887              7.91              6.69             -4.30
1888              8.09              7.38             -4.05
1889              8.32              7.65             -4.24
1890              7.97              7.59             -4.01
1891              8.02              7.68             -3.93
1892              8.07              5.90             -5.34
1893              8.06              7.41             -4.04
1894              8.16              6.96             -4.32
1895              8.15              7.92             -3.41
1896              8.21              7.41             -3.57
1897              8.29              8.35             -2.88
1898              8.18              8.44             -3.26
1899              8.40              7.19             -4.10
1900              8.50              8.00             -3.49
1901              8.54              8.80             -3.03
1902              8.30              8.41             -3.19
1903              8.22              7.08             -3.86
1904              8.09              8.02             -3.32
1905              8.23              8.09             -3.64
1906              8.38              7.90             -3.87
1907              7.95              8.12             -3.55
1908              8.19              7.12             -4.30
1909              8.18              8.10             -3.27
1910              8.22              7.13             -3.97
1911              8.18              7.91             -3.31
1912              8.17              7.66             -3.66
1913              8.30              8.82             -2.33
1914              8.59              7.90             -3.42
1915              8.59              8.31             -2.93
1916              8.23              7.85             -3.78
1917              8.02              7.55             -3.80
1918              8.13              7.65             -3.40
1919              8.38              8.44             -2.94
1920              8.36              8.74             -2.71
1921              8.57              7.60             -3.43
1922              8.41              8.21             -3.19
1923              8.42              7.91             -3.50
1924              8.51              7.48             -3.18
1925              8.53              8.78             -2.22
1926              8.73              7.93             -3.51
1927              8.52              8.29             -2.63
1928              8.63              7.48             -3.66
1929              8.24              7.67             -3.17
1930              8.63              8.06             -2.90
1931              8.72              9.16             -2.05
1932              8.71              7.38             -3.45
1933              8.34              7.99             -3.13
1934              8.63              7.74             -3.62
1935              8.52              7.81             -3.53
1936              8.55              7.88             -3.22
1937              8.70              8.42             -2.60
1938              8.86              8.53             -2.77
1939              8.76              7.94             -3.35
1940              8.76              8.35             -3.01
1941              8.77              8.72             -2.61
1942              8.73              8.02             -3.28
1943              8.76              9.04             -1.93
1944              8.85              8.13             -2.91
1945              8.58              8.48             -2.55
1946              8.68              8.11             -2.99
1947              8.80              9.14             -2.35
1948              8.75              8.84             -2.43
1949              8.59              7.61             -3.62
1950              8.37              7.77             -3.52
1951              8.63              8.66             -2.58
1952              8.64              8.54             -2.63
1953              8.87              7.67             -3.58
1954              8.56              8.91             -2.03
1955              8.63              7.91             -3.06
1956              8.28              8.01             -2.97
1957              8.73              8.98             -1.77
1958              8.77              8.39             -2.41
1959              8.73              8.22             -2.62
1960              8.58              8.38             -2.38
1961              8.80              8.66             -2.51
1962              8.75              8.67             -2.68
1963              8.86              8.38             -2.55
1964              8.41              8.42             -2.53
1965              8.53              8.05             -3.04
1966              8.60              8.40             -2.87
1967              8.70              7.87             -3.06
1968              8.52              7.23             -3.30
1969              8.60              8.29             -2.58
1970              8.70              8.53             -2.53
1971              8.60              7.39             -3.55
1972              8.50              8.49             -2.31
1973              8.95              7.46             -2.89
1974              8.47              8.48             -2.26
1975              8.74              8.40             -2.45
1976              8.35              7.76             -2.65
1977              8.85              8.01             -2.52
1978              8.69              8.07             -2.62
1979              8.73              8.47             -2.46
1980              8.98              9.27             -1.30
1981              9.17              8.09             -2.78
1982              8.64              8.75             -1.65
1983              9.03              8.34             -2.23
1984              8.69              8.39             -2.22
1985              8.66              8.82             -2.01
1986              8.83              8.70             -2.34
1987              8.99              8.86             -1.80
1988              9.20              8.10             -2.60
1989              8.92              8.56             -1.94
1990              9.23              8.51             -1.91
1991              9.18              8.91             -1.65
1992              8.84              8.67             -1.92
1993              8.87              8.34             -2.27
1994              9.04              8.90             -1.77
1995              9.35              8.35             -2.51
1996              9.04              8.59             -2.13
1997              9.20              8.56             -1.78
1998              9.52              8.88             -1.73
1999              9.29              8.35             -2.32
2000              9.20              8.83             -2.08
2001              9.41              9.46             -1.32
2002              9.57              9.56             -1.48
2003              9.53              8.90             -1.65
2004              9.32              9.03             -1.38
2005              9.70              8.62             -1.94
2006              9.53              10.08             -0.82
2007              9.73              8.15             -2.38
2008              9.43              9.18             -1.76
2009              9.51              9.24             -1.68
2010              9.70              8.72             -2.03
2011              9.52              8.69             -2.23
2012              9.51              9.26             -1.73
2013              9.61              9.33             -1.75
2014              9.57              9.43             -1.52
2015              9.83              10.73             0.29
```

The code isn’t giving any output

I am expecting that I have gnuplot for this data any help would be nice. I am trying to read only from 2000-2015 and post box plot with error bar for each of the data

Comment: "doesn't work", doesn't help much in diagnosing the problem. Edit your question to include the exact text of any error messages. If no errors, then post the failing output . Good luck

Comment: Are you asking [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78226172/7295599) which has been closed just under a new user name? If yes, please either edit or delete the old question.

Comment: Are you sure your data is correct? For example 2005: average temperature is `9.70` and maximum temperature is `8.62`?

Comment: The word "boxplot" means different things to different people, so it is unclear exactly what kind of plot you are aiming for.  To gnuplot "with boxplot", "with boxes", and "with yerrorbars" are three different types of plot.  Your script and description seem to mix these up.   Have a look through the various style examples at http://gnuplot.info/docs_6.0/Plotting_Styles.html     I am guessing maybe you actually want plot style 'with boxerrorbars`?

Comment: One second thought, maybe you actually want plot style `with candlesticks`?